# Different values in tag badge counter

Tags: bug, badge-progress

Tag badge counter widget in profile displays different values than the modal allowing you to select a different badge to track.

[image: profile widget]

[image]

Browser: Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

OS: Win 10

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It will take time. try to clear cache

Comment: I tried to clear cache, tried different browser, even incognito window but I am still facing this issue; on site my score in `python` tag is shown as 57 but in android app it shows 67